# Difference between using echo with one greater than sign and two greater than signs

Tags: linux, echo

I am reading the Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).  In step 6 of 1.3, there's the following code:

```
> echo foo> test.txt
> echo bar>> test.txt
```

I would like to ask what is the difference between using one greater than sign and two greater than signs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the former recreate the file on each invocation
- the later *append* to file. Create the file the first time if not exists

Check

```
man bash | less +/'Redirecting Output'
```